# leaflet set path to local map tiles works offline but not online

Tags: maps, leaflet, tile

I want to use map tiles offline. The tiles are made with Maperitive. This is the HTML with leaflet JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>map - test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimal-ui" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <!-- leafletjs -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            html, body, #map {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map">
        <script>

            var map = L.map('map', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                minZoom: 16,
                maxBounds: [
                    //south west
                    [47.918760313911896, 9.25198432059355],
                    //north east
                    [47.929235549307315, 9.26072925925386]
                ], 
            }).setView([47.923997931609605, 9.2563567899237054], 17);

            L.tileLayer('../img/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {  
                tms: true // Do I need that?
            }) .addTo(map);

            L.marker([47.92458, 9.25630]) .addTo(map);

        </script>
    </div>        
  </body>
</html>
```

The code works offline on my computer but non online on my server. The folder with the tiles is stored on the server. The path to the tiles is correct.

What is my fault?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.

It´s not the code. The tile-PNGs caused a 403 error. I rendered the tiles with Maperitive on a Windows 8 computer. Then I transferred them to a Mac. From there I put them on the server via ftp.

Now I transferred the tiles directly from the Windows to the server. **And all is ok**.

What happens between the Windows and the Mac that corruptes the PNGs?